# Passing data to fragment viewmodel mvvmcross

Tags: c#, android-fragments, mvvmcross

so I have an activity that has a tabbed page with 2 fragments.

```
  public class RecipeDetailActivity : BaseFragmentActivity<RecipeDetailViewModel>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.RecipeDetailView);

            AttachActionBar();
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.Title = "Recipe details";

            var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.main_view_pager);

            if (viewPager != null)
            {
                var fragments = new List<MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo>();
                fragments.Add(
                    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Ingrediente", typeof(RecipeFlavoursFragment), typeof(RecipeFlavoursViewModel)));
                fragments.Add(
                    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Flavours", typeof(RecipeIngridientsFragment), typeof(RecipeIngridientsViewModel)));

                viewPager.Adapter = new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter(this, SupportFragmentManager, fragments);


                viewPager.Adapter = new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter(this, SupportFragmentManager, fragments);
                var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.main_tablayout);
                tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        }
    }
```

I show this page using the following code.

```
   private void SelectRecipe(RecipeModel recipe)
   {
            var recipeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recipe);

            ShowViewModel<RecipeDetailViewModel>(new { recipe = recipeJson });
   }
```

Now what I would like is to pass some data to child view models. 
**RecipeFlavoursViewModel
RecipeIngridientsViewModel**

I've tried so far : 
Using **parameterValueObject**

```
        fragments.Add(
            new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Ingrediente", typeof(RecipeFlavoursFragment), typeof(RecipeFlavoursViewModel), new { recipe = ViewModel.Recipe }));
```

Using IMvxBundle

In **RecipeDetailViewModel**

```
 protected override void SaveStateToBundle(IMvxBundle bundle)
 {
            bundle.Data["Recipe"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Recipe);

            base.SaveStateToBundle(bundle);
 }
```

In **RecipeIngridientsViewModel**

```
protected override void InitFromBundle(IMvxBundle parameters)
        {
            base.InitFromBundle(parameters);

            if (parameters.Data.Count != 0)
            {
                Recipe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecipeModel>(parameters.Data["recipe"]);
            }
        }
```

None of them have worked so far. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Do I have to use the navigation service  from MvvmCross 5 to be able to use InitFromBundle and SaveStateToBundle.

**InitFromBundle** it's called everytime my fragments is displayed, but **SaveStateToBundle** from **RecipeDetailViewModel** never gets called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to do this, you could take advantage of the [MvxViewPagerFragmentPresentationAttribute](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/presenters/android-view-presenter?scroll=760#mvxviewpagerfragmentpresentationattribute-appcompat-only) so that the `Presenter` takes the responsibility to show the fragments and you just show the ViewModels passing the `Recipe` parameter as any other but it has some minor bugs for the moment.

However one way to solve this is to have in your `RecipeDetailViewModel` properties with the fragments' ViewModels you want to have in your `ViewPager` and load them in the `Initialize` so then you can reference them from your `RecipeDetailActivity`:

Using Mvx 5 you can use new [Navigation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation) to show the ViewModels. If the details are openned from `RecipeListViewModel` then:

```
public class RecipeDetailViewModelArgs
{
    public RecipeDetailViewModelArgs(RecipeModel recipe)
    {
        this.Recipe = recipe;
    }

    public RecipeModel Recipe { get; }
}

public class RecipeListViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService navigationService;

    public RecipeListViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    private async Task SelectRecipe(RecipeModel recipe)
    {
        await this.navigationService.Navigate<RecipeDetailViewModel, RecipeDetailViewModelArgs>(new RecipeDetailViewModelArgs(recipe));
    }
}
```

Then in your details ViewModel you just cache the recipe, load the children ViewModels (ingredients and flavours) and set the recipe to them:

```
public class RecipeDetailViewModel : MvxViewModel<RecipeDetailViewModelArgs>
{
    private readonly IMvxViewModelLoader mvxViewModelLoader;
    private readonly IMvxJsonConverter jsonConverter;
    private RecipeModel recipe;

    public RecipeDetailViewModel(IMvxViewModelLoader mvxViewModelLoader, IMvxJsonConverter jsonConverter)
    {
        this.mvxViewModelLoader = mvxViewModelLoader;
        this.jsonConverter = jsonConverter;
    }

    public override void Prepare(RecipeDetailViewModelArgs parameter)
    {
        this.recipe = parameter.Recipe;
    }

    protected override void SaveStateToBundle(IMvxBundle bundle)
    {
        base.SaveStateToBundle(bundle);

        bundle.Data["RecipeKey"] = this.jsonConverter.SerializeObject(this.recipe);
    }

    protected override void ReloadFromBundle(IMvxBundle state)
    {
        base.ReloadFromBundle(state);

        this.recipe = this.jsonConverter.DeserializeObject<RecipeModel>(state.Data["RecipeKey"]);
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        await base.Initialize();

        this.InitializeChildrenViewModels();
    }

    public RecipeFlavoursViewModel FlavoursViewModel { get; private set; }

    public RecipeIngridientsViewModel IngredientsViewModel { get; private set; }

    protected virtual void InitializeChildrenViewModels()
    {
        // Load each childre ViewModel and set the recipe
        this.FlavoursViewModel = this.mvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel(new MvxViewModelRequest<RecipeFlavoursViewModel>(null, null), null);
        this.FlavoursViewModel.Recipe = this.recipe;

        this.IngredientsViewModel = this.mvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel(new MvxViewModelRequest<RecipeIngridientsViewModel>(null, null), null);
        this.FlavoursViewModel.Recipe = this.recipe;
    }
}
```

Then when you load the `ViewPager` you can take advantage from the other constructor of `MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo` => `public MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo (string title, string tag, Type fragmentType, IMvxViewModel viewModel, object parameterValuesObject = null)` so you can pass the ViewModels previously loaded:

```
this.viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPagerDetails);
if (viewPager != null)
{
    var fragments = new List<MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo>();
    fragments.Add(new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Ingredients", "RecipeIngridientsViewModelTag", typeof(RecipeIngridientsView), this.ViewModel.IngridientsViewModel));
    fragments.Add(new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Flavours", "RecipeFlavoursViewModelTag", typeof(RecipeFlavoursView), this.ViewModel.FlavoursViewModel));

    this.viewPager.Adapter = new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter(this.Activity, this.ChildFragmentManager, fragments);
}
```

That's it.

---

BTW if you don't want to use Navigation or you are not using Mvx 5.x then you just Initialize the children ViewModels in the `void Start()` method.

And to conclude if you want to change values of your `Recipe` from the children one simple way is to have a Singleton initialized with your `Recipe` and then you just Inject the singleton in the constructors so you always have the reference to the same Recipe and you don't have to pass the Recipe object forth & back to those ViewModels and merge the changes made from each of them. More info in [MvvmCross: Accessing models by reference from everywhere](http://nmilcoff.com/2016/09/12/mvvmcross-accesing-models-by-reference-from-everywhere/)

HIH